# coulomb and ampere calculation reg

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, ampere-hour

when I am reading the IC datasheet ,operating voltage is they were mentioned 5v,300mA.its means 300mA per sec/min/hour.

Because I have to calculate battery power for a circuit.

1 coulomb= 1 ampere.

so please any one you conform the basic thing it will consume the 300mA per second/minutes/hours.

Comment: 1 coulomb PER SECOND = 1 ampere

Comment: 300mA forever, while it's operating.

Comment: you mean it will take the 300mA forever.There is no time limit . 300ma=0.3 coulomb/sec                                                                           0.3*60=18columb/min                                                                        0.3*3600=1080 c/hr                                                                                        1080*24=25920 c/hr

Comment: It will take 300 mA as long as the battery can supply it. With a 3000 mAh battery, this time is 10 hours.